# INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'

Tags: sql-server

We are getting the below message sometimes while executing the stored procedure, after that without any change deleting and re-executing the stored procedure it is working fine.

> DBCORE INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Kindly help us to understand this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anyone hits this error after having deployed via a Visual Studio database project then it's worth checking the properties of your stored procedure file. If this is set to **Project Default** then go to the properties of your database project > Project Settings and click the Database Setting button.

You can turn these two values (and others) to be on by default as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

This will only fix the issue if you have changes to the procedure however; a schema compare and subsequent update will not change the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` in the stored procedure unless there are changes to the body of the procedure. It will prevent the problem from reoccurring on a subsequent schema updated though.

Comment: Alternatively change the settings for your stored proc like this in the .sqlproj file: `<Build Include="StoredProcedures\MyStoredProc.sql"><QuotedIdentifier>On</QuotedIdentifier><AnsiNulls>On</AnsiNulls></Build>`

Answer (score 41):

`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is a "sticky" option so the setting in effect when the procedure was created is used at runtime. Since no procedure changes were made, the error suggests the stored procedure was created with `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` and an index with one of the types mentioned in the error message was created/dropped.

Recreate or alter the stored procedure from a session with both `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` and `ANSI_NULLS ON` to avoid the problem going forward.

**EDIT:**

Per the answer by @Leonidius and related comments, the `SQLCMD` command-line utility defaults to `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` for backwards compatibility. This behavior differs from SSMS and is a common gotcha when deployment scripts don't explicitly include `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` statements before creating stored procedures and other objects.

I strongly suggest one make a habit of specifying the `-I` `SQLCMD` argument to ensure `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` is not set inadvertently.

Answer (score 28):

In my case I had to add -I parameter to sqlcmd.exe command line when loading stored procedures in the bulk mode.

Comment: SQLCMD defaults to `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` for backwards compatibility so the `-I` option is needed when the executed scripts don't include `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` before creating stored procedures.

Comment: My bcp version didn't have `-I`, but adding `-q` did the trick

Comment: Oh my god thanks, I was looking for this for days

Answer (score 16):

I was running into this problem so I created all my Job's Steps into Stored procedures in MS SQL. When using the template it automatically has the following

```
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I got had the same message but the issue was related to the position of the BEGIN TRANSACTION declaration which it was misplaced.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in an SQL Job Step because I was trying to set a column named Status. So at the very top I added
`GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO`
and in my SET statement I added double quotes to my column Status

```
UPDATE QES.dbo.WDQ894_IdsToProcess SET "Status" = 3
```